# Big Query Service Account access revoked?

Tags: google-bigquery

I had been accessing Google Big Query with a service account successfully for several days. I had several tests that would connect and perform single functions successfully.

Now, without changing any code, or anything through the API console, I consistently get an "invalid_grant" from all of my API calls.

I have come now-where near breaching the courtesy request limits, and I have billing enabled.

Is there something that I could have done to get my access revoked?

I have tried creating another service account with, with another private key etc, with no success.

I have put my new credentials into the sample code given here: [Authenticating Google API with a service account with Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827817/authenticating-google-api-with-a-service-account-with-java-api) without success.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had service account authorization working successfully with BigQuery in the past, and it suddenly stopped working (and it's consistently not working), I would guess that the issue has something to do with the clock on your server.

I would check this first - if the clock seems to be off, use something like NTPdate (http://doc.ntp.org/3-5.93e/ntpdate.html) to make sure that it is synced with an NTP server.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if that was the issue.. but in two-cases I had re-synced my Mac's time (amongst other things), and it started working again. 

But this is good to know anyway.