# Sharing google calendar event using private URL and google api v3

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I require to share all person's google calendar in company.

Before this I have studied Google api v2  and its possible to get event from calendar if I have private URL.

But since its depricated now, I am thinking to develop this using api v3. I am studying the code but not finding any method to that can give me events using private URL in it.

is it possible in api v3?

According to tutorial I need to get api activated from user. I want to manage minimum from user side.

we are using Google Apps at our company. Which can be suitable solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for this is `events#list`, there are some examples on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) page.

To avoid having the user authenticating, you should use a service account. You didn't mention the programming language, but there's a PHP example [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php).

To access a private calendar from Google Apps you have to give permissions to he service account as described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).

Comment: Hello Vinicious, At this time I am using java for the codding.. When I look for the code its asking for Client Secret e.g. developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate But client Secret is not available for service account.. Can you give any example that can return calendar events using service account.. I am trying code but gives Error 404 (For testing I am using general gmail account not Google apps) Thanks

Comment: @compyutech check the Java lib documentation: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_accounts There's also an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11835103/81108 (this is for the BigQuery API, but the auth process is the same for the Calendar API). If you can't get it to work, please ask another question with your code.