# Gmail Java API with ServiceAccount error 401

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to use Gmail API from a backend java. starting from my maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev20200406-1.30.9</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have downloaded a p12 Keystore from the google API manager and I created a service account

```
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("privatekey", "somepass".toCharArray()); 
ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.newBuilder()
                 .setClientEmail("somestuff@developer.gserviceaccount.com")                                                                                         
                 .setServiceAccountUser("somestuff@developer.gserviceaccount.com")                                                                                                
                 .setClientId("somenumber")                                                                                                  
                 .setScopes(SCOPES)                                                                                                  
                 .setPrivateKey(key).build();
```

now this seems to be working

```java
serviceAccountCredentials.refresh();
```

generate a token  on the form of

**ya29.c.Ko8BygeNYc2Onx2IZpK-ocaHKTiCxOcYYK7nbTg8uE0gyqc8rXROuiVJ7oXCfnYD1pDOyHXiy_K5Eyk3aV3epgjtnr2WVCP_xpWCxq-BExh4i1aIXW9m7gkkUtbteXaD1nETUwIc6n9Uz2oCJSU4jrodFv4n4drxlSGd7my0LcxrMk_E5cFY7jo-Vt40i58g5QY**

Now the part I can not get to work

```java
HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(serviceAccountCredentials);

Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), requestInitializer).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
Gmail.Users.Labels.List list = service.users().labels().list("b@someemail")
                               .setAccessToken(credential.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
```

I have also done all gmail configuration suggested by [Gmail REST API : 400 Bad Request + Failed Precondition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327846/gmail-rest-api-400-bad-request-failed-precondition)

But I keep to get

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

### Note

You are using domain delegation you should follow [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) guide to authorize the service account to use the Gmail Service with this particular scope.

### Approach

Once you created the credentials object starting from your service account key, just proceed to create the Gmail service builder this way:

```
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID = "your-service-account-id";
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "your-app-name";

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("privatekey", "somepass".toCharArray()); 

HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(key)
                .setServiceAccountEmail("user@email")
                .build();

Gmail service =  new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

Now you can use the Gmail service directly without the need to specify again the access token nor the credentials. Just like this:

```
ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list("b@somemail").execute();
```

### Reference

[Java Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)

[Service Account Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835103/7453656)

Comment: @alessndro the signature for the method the builder has now Builder(http.HttpTransport transport, jsonFactory, com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) what dependency are you using ?

Comment: I'm using the last version available at: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/. `'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev110-1.25.0'`